# ComboBox и Условие

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть вот такой вот ComboBox[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу прогнать его через условие вот таким вот образом

```
HowMuch.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        String prove = String.valueOf(Box1.getValue());
        String prove1 = String.valueOf(Box2.getValue());
        String prove2 = Money.getText();

        if(!prove.isEmpty() || !prove1.isEmpty() || prove2.isEmpty()){
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/Error4.fxml"));
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Parent first = loader.getRoot();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(first));
            stage.showAndWait();
        }else{
            check(prove);
            check2(prove1);
        }
```

Дело в том что данные полученные полем proove из ComboBox он всегда считает пустыми не в зависимости от того что я выберу в боксе или что я не выберу то бишь всегда выдает (true) и условие не работает. Что я могу сделать что бы он понимал что я что то выбрал или ничего не выбирал. Заранее благодарен

Comment: У Box1, Box2 какие типы, ComboBox<String>?

Comment: Да все поля в String

Comment: Опишите словами условие, по которой первая ветка if должна выполняться. Если хотя бы одно поле пустое, должно вывести ошибку?

Comment: Да все верно, условие такого:

Comment: Если в Box1 или в Box2 ничего не выбрано, или в Textfield ничего не введено, то он выводит ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) возвращает выбранный объект (строку в данном случае) или `null` (если ничего не выбрано), дополнительно в строку через `String.valueOf()` преобразовывать не нужно, причем у вас должно бросать исключение, когда в комбо ничего не выбрано (`.getValue()` вернул `null`).

Нужно убрать эту конвертацию, и для проверки на "пустоту" проверять значения на `null`:

```
String prove = Box1.getValue();
String prove1 = Box2.getValue();
String prove2 = Money.getText();

if(prove == null || prove1 == null || prove2.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Вот блин я ведь так делал просто зачем то по глупости преобразовывал в строку. Спасибо вам